# Laravel (nova) endpoint get request returns resource in browser, but 403 in unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, get, laravel-nova

If I go via the browser to the following link in the browser:

```
 'http://localhost/nova-api/colors'
```

Laravel will return what I requested,
However if I perform the same get request in a unit test:

```
$user = User::all()->first();
\Auth::login($user);

$response = $this->get('http://localhost/nova-api/colors');

dd($response->getStatusCode());
```

The response is a 403.

Why can't I retrieve the same resource array via the unit test as via the browser?

Answer (score 1):

403 means you are forbidden to go to the route...
try using actingAs() instead of login

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1, This solution does not work for me however :-)

Comment: @Peterverleg If the solution doesn't work, please do not accept it. You can up vote if its useful